# Running RMI with javafxports on Android

Tags: java, android, rmi, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I created an application in the Gluon project. On the PC, my application calls remote methods and everything works fine. But when I collect the project for Android (Tasks -> apk -> apkDebug) then I install on the device then the program does not start (Hangs up and shows a black screen). Help me understand what the problem is!

Here is the code:

```
public class SecView implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public TextField typeBatteryField;

    @FXML
    public TextField capacityBatteryField;

    @FXML
    public TextField chargingField;

    @FXML
    public TextField speedChargerBatteryField;

    @FXML
    public TextField maximumLimitChargeField;
    private ChargerService chargerService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }

    @FXML
    public void buttonClick() {
        try {
            Integer maxLim = Integer.parseInt(maximumLimitChargeField.getText());
            Integer spdBat = Integer.parseInt(speedChargerBatteryField.getText());
            ChargerService chargerSer = getChargerService();
            chargerSer.setMaximumLimitCharge(maxLim);
            chargerSer.setSpeedChargerBattery(spdBat);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SecView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private ChargerService getChargerService() {
        if (chargerService == null) {
            try {
                System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.0.75", 5005);
                String className = ChargerService.class.getSimpleName();
                chargerService = (ChargerService) reg.lookup(className);
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
        return chargerService;
    } }
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.5'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.mobileui.MobileUi'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.3.2'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.2.4'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'connectivity', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.mobileui.**.*',
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: With your device connected, on your machine open a console, navigate to your Android SDK folder, enter the platform-tools folder, and run `adb logcat  -v threadtime`. Open the app and try to find out a stacktrace with the exception that causes the black screen. If that doesn't help you figuring out the issue, post it here.